# I have to manually connect to the Postgres instance in Render to reestabilish connection in Render

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I deployed my backend Node application to Render, and created a postgres database instance on Render as well. When I created the database, it gave me the urls of the internal or external connection, as well as the psql command to manually make the connection in psql command prompt:

[image]

Since my backend app and postgres database are both deployed in Render, I used the internal connection url to connect my node backend to the database, and it worked just fine. Basically, my app is an ecommerce, where my frontend React app will make HTTP requests to my express backend API, which in turn will perform CRUD operations with postgres and that response will be displayed on the frontend UI.

The problem is, I noticed that after some time, something like 2 or so hours, my connection to the database is lost. In my home page in the React app, if there is data coming from the database, it was supposed to look like this:

[image]

but when there is no data, in other words, the connection to the database is lost, it looks like this:

[image]

Only when I enter pgAdmin4 and manually connect to the database with the psql command Render gave me, it works again. Why is this happening? If there is no operation involving the database for a few hours, its connection is lost? I read the docs and didn't find anything like that. My db instance is the free tier one and my React is deployed in Vercel.